# Inversly proportional theory

Tags: inverse

Let's begin our discussion:

Many people find that time seems to pass more quickly as you get older. So, the older you are, the shorter a year seems. Let's model this experience mathematically. Let's theorize that your perception of a length of time is inversely proportional to your age. We will investigate together and determine as a group if we think this is a good model of the true experience.

Let's use ptime as the variable for your perception of a length of time, and use age as the variable for your age.

1. Our theory is that your perception of a length of time is inversely proportional to your age. Using the variables above, how would you state the theory in a mathematical equation?
2. Using this theory, how long will a year seem when you are two times older than you are now? To investigate, let ptime1 be how long a year seems now, and let ptime2 be how long a year will seem when you are twice as old. Pick a number for ptime1 (maybe a year feels like 157 days to you, for instance), and then calculate ptime2. Pick a number for ptime1 that is different from other students.

Comment: Not sure what this is.  Was this a homework problem you were given?  Is it a homework problem you are proposing to give to your students?  In either case, what is it that you are asking us to do?

Comment: is a discussion on my pre calculus class. I just don't know where to plug what using the y=k*1/x

Comment: Well, the problem set really walks you through what to do.  My suggestion:  edit your post to show what you have tried.  Presumably you can do the first part, yes?  I mean you more or less answered it in your comment.  Then try to carry out the steps indicated in the second part.  Once you have done that, people here will, I think, be glad to help clear up the details.